# Equal space between grid items with first and last pinned to container edges

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid with CSS Grid that has the first item aligned left with no left margin and the last item aligned right, no margin and with equal space in between all items.

How can I change the alignment of the first and last items but keep the distance between the rest equal?

I have this so far..

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.griditem1 {
  background: teal;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.griditem2 {
  background: tan;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.griditem3 {
  background: wheat;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.griditem4 {
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="griditem1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using flexbox:

```css
div.gridcontainer{
  background:yellow;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  text-align:center;
}
div.gridcontainer > div {
  width:100px;
}
.griditem1 {background:teal;}
.griditem2 {background:tan;}
.griditem3 {background:wheat;}
.griditem4 {background:grey;}
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="griditem1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 3</p>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, flexbox was a much better option

Answer (score 5):

You have at least two simple and clean options with CSS Grid.

### 1. `justify-content: space-between`

The `justify-content` property can be used in Grid Layout, just like in Flex Layout.

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.griditem1 { background: teal; }
.griditem2 { background: tan; }
.griditem3 { background: wheat; }
.griditem4 { background: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="griditem1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2. `grid-column-gap` or `grid-gap`

CSS Grid provides the `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` properties. The shorthand for both is `grid-gap`. These properties allow you to create space **between** grid items. They don't target the space between items and the container. Again, they only work between items (i.e., the gutters).

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.griditem1 { background: teal; }
.griditem2 { background: tan; }
.griditem3 { background: wheat; }
.griditem4 { background: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="griditem1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are limiting the grid items to 100px width - you could originally set the columns with that width and remove it from the item styles.

Also, to justify the items, you could use: `justify-content: space-between;`

```
.gridcontainer {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px); /* 4 columns of 100px */
   text-align: center;
   background: yellow;
   justify-content: space-between; /* justify items */
}
```

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.griditem1 {
  background: teal;
}

.griditem2 {
  background: tan;
}

.griditem3 {
  background: wheat;
}

.griditem4 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="griditem1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
    <p>Grid Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```